# how to crop only face instead of whole body in oval form using Google Vision Face detection API in android

Tags: java, android, crop, face-detection, google-vision

**I want to make app which take photos only with faces but I get whole image instead of face when I save into my storage file. So how to crop  face and save into storage with the help google vision face detection API.**

So how to use frame in my code to get face list as well as how can I convert into bitmap and save into my storage.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">


  <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
      android:id="@+id/preview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
        android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



  </com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>


</LinearLayout>
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:id="@+id/take_pic_btn"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:background="@color/green"
      android:layout_margin="10dp"
      android:text="Take Image"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:textAllCaps="false"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**FaceTrackerActivity .java**

```
public final class FaceTrackerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "FaceTracker";

    private CameraSource mCameraSource = null;

    private CameraSourcePreview mPreview;
    private GraphicOverlay mGraphicOverlay;

    private static final int RC_HANDLE_GMS = 9001;
    // permission request codes need to be < 256
    private static final int RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM = 2;
    private Button takePicButton;
    FaceDetector detector;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPreview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mGraphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay) findViewById(R.id.faceOverlay);
        takePicButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.take_pic_btn);

        int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int gc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && gc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            createCameraSource();
        } else {
            requestCameraPermission();
        }
        takePicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"dilip",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                captureImage();


            }
        });
    }


    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        Log.w(TAG, "Camera permission is not granted. Requesting permission");

        final String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) && !ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
            return;
        }

        final Activity thisActivity = this;

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions,
                        RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
            }
        };

        Snackbar.make(mGraphicOverlay, R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(R.string.ok, listener)
                .show();
    }


    private void createCameraSource() {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
       /* FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .build();

        detector.setProcessor(
                new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory())
                        .build());*/

        detector= new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
                .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
                .build();
        MyFaceDetector myFaceDetector = new MyFaceDetector(detector);

        detector.setProcessor(
                new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(new GraphicFaceTrackerFactory())
                        .build());

        mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, myFaceDetector)
                .build();

        if (!detector.isOperational()) {
           }

        mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, detector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
                .setRequestedFps(10.0f)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Restarts the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        startCameraSource();
    }

    /**
     * Stops the camera.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mPreview.stop();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.release();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback for the result from requesting permissions. This method
     * is invoked for every call on {@link #requestPermissions(String[], int)}.
     * <p>
     * <strong>Note:</strong> It is possible that the permissions request interaction
     * with the user is interrupted. In this case you will receive empty permissions
     * and results arrays which should be treated as a cancellation.
     * </p>
     *
     * @param requestCode  The request code passed in {@link #requestPermissions(String[], int)}.
     * @param permissions  The requested permissions. Never null.
     * @param grantResults The grant results for the corresponding permissions
     *                     which is either {@link PackageManager#PERMISSION_GRANTED}
     *                     or {@link PackageManager#PERMISSION_DENIED}. Never null.
     * @see #requestPermissions(String[], int)
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode != RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got unexpected permission result: " + requestCode);
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            return;
        }

        if (grantResults.length != 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Camera permission granted - initialize the camera source");
            // we have permission, so create the camerasource
            createCameraSource();
            return;
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Permission not granted: results len = " + grantResults.length +
                " Result code = " + (grantResults.length > 0 ? grantResults[0] : "(empty)"));

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Face Tracker sample")
                .setMessage(R.string.no_camera_permission)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, listener)
                .show();
    }

    //==============================================================================================
    // Camera Source Preview
    //==============================================================================================

    /**
     * Starts or restarts the camera source, if it exists.  If the camera source doesn't exist yet
     * (e.g., because onResume was called before the camera source was created), this will be called
     * again when the camera source is created.
     */
    private void startCameraSource() {

        // check that the device has play services available.
        int code = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(
                getApplicationContext());
        if (code != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            Dialog dlg =
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, code, RC_HANDLE_GMS);
            dlg.show();
        }

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            try {
                mPreview.start(mCameraSource, mGraphicOverlay);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to start camera source.", e);
                mCameraSource.release();
                mCameraSource = null;
            }
        }
    }

    //==============================================================================================
    // Graphic Face Tracker
    //==============================================================================================

    /**
     * Factory for creating a face tracker to be associated with a new face.  The multiprocessor
     * uses this factory to create face trackers as needed -- one for each individual.
     */
    private class GraphicFaceTrackerFactory implements MultiProcessor.Factory<Face> {
        @Override
        public Tracker<Face> create(Face face) {
            return new GraphicFaceTracker(mGraphicOverlay);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Face tracker for each detected individual. This maintains a face graphic within the app's
     * associated face overlay.
     */
    private class GraphicFaceTracker extends Tracker<Face> {
        private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;
        private FaceGraphic mFaceGraphic;

        GraphicFaceTracker(GraphicOverlay overlay) {
            mOverlay = overlay;
            mFaceGraphic = new FaceGraphic(overlay);
        }

        /**
         * Start tracking the detected face instance within the face overlay.
         */
        @Override
        public void onNewItem(int faceId, Face item) {
            mFaceGraphic.setId(faceId);
        }

    **`strong text`**
        @Override
        public void onUpdate(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults, Face face) {
            mOverlay.add(mFaceGraphic);
            mFaceGraphic.updateFace(face);
        }

        /**
         * Hide the graphic when the corresponding face was not detected.  This can happen for
         * intermediate frames temporarily (e.g., if the face was momentarily blocked from
         * view).
         */
        @Override
        public void onMissing(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults) {
            mOverlay.remove(mFaceGraphic);
        }

        /**
         * Called when the face is assumed to be gone for good. Remove the graphic annotation from
         * the overlay.
         */
        @Override
        public void onDone() {
            mOverlay.remove(mFaceGraphic);
        }
    }


    private void captureImage() {
        mPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       final Bitmap drawingCache = mPreview.getDrawingCache();



        mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {
                int orientation = Exif.getOrientation(bytes);


                Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                Bitmap picture = rotateImage(temp,orientation);
                Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mGraphicOverlay.getWidth(),mGraphicOverlay.getHeight(),picture.getConfig());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                matrix.setScale((float)overlay.getWidth()/(float)picture.getWidth(),(float)overlay.getHeight()/(float)picture.getHeight());

                // mirror by inverting scale and translating
                matrix.preScale(-1, 1);
                matrix.postTranslate(canvas.getWidth(), 0);

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                canvas.drawBitmap(picture,matrix,paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(drawingCache,0,0,paint);

                try {
                    String mainpath = getExternalStorageDirectory() + separator + "MaskIt" + separator + "images" + separator;
                    File basePath = new File(mainpath);
                    if (!basePath.exists())
                        Log.d("CAPTURE_BASE_PATH", basePath.mkdirs() ? "Success": "Failed");
                    String path = mainpath + "photo_" + getPhotoTime() + ".jpg";
                    File captureFile = new File(path);
                    captureFile.createNewFile();
                    if (!captureFile.exists())
                        Log.d("CAPTURE_FILE_PATH", captureFile.createNewFile() ? "Success": "Failed");
                    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(captureFile);
                    overlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    stream.flush();
                    stream.close();
                    picture.recycle();
                    drawingCache.recycle();
                    mPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private String getPhotoTime() {
                DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hhmmss");
                dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
                Date today = new Date();
                String s = dateFormatter.format(today);
                return  s;
            }
        });
    }




    private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bm, int i) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (i) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bm;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bm;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bm.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }





}
```

**CameraSourcePreview.java**

```
package com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.common.images.Size;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraSourcePreview extends ViewGroup {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraSourcePreview";

    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private boolean mStartRequested;
    private boolean mSurfaceAvailable;
    private CameraSource mCameraSource;

    private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;

    public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
        mStartRequested = false;
        mSurfaceAvailable = false;

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
        addView(mSurfaceView);
    }

    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource) throws IOException {
        if (cameraSource == null) {
            stop();
        }

        mCameraSource = cameraSource;

        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mStartRequested = true;
            startIfReady();
        }
    }

    public void start(CameraSource cameraSource, GraphicOverlay overlay) throws IOException {
        mOverlay = overlay;
        start(cameraSource);
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.stop();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            mCameraSource.release();
            mCameraSource = null;
        }
    }

    private void startIfReady() throws IOException {
        if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {
            mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
            if (mOverlay != null) {
                Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
                int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
                if (isPortraitMode()) {
                    // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by
                    // 90 degrees
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(min, max, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                } else {
                    mOverlay.setCameraInfo(max, min, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
                }
                mOverlay.clear();
            }
            mStartRequested = false;
        }
    }

    private class SurfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surface) {
            mSurfaceAvailable = true;
            try {
                startIfReady();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surface) {
            mSurfaceAvailable = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        int previewWidth = 320;
        int previewHeight = 240;
        if (mCameraSource != null) {
            Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
            if (size != null) {
                previewWidth = size.getWidth();
                previewHeight = size.getHeight();
            }
        }

        // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
        if (isPortraitMode()) {
            int tmp = previewWidth;
            previewWidth = previewHeight;
            previewHeight = tmp;
        }

        final int viewWidth = right - left;
        final int viewHeight = bottom - top;

        int childWidth;
        int childHeight;
        int childXOffset = 0;
        int childYOffset = 0;
        float widthRatio = (float) viewWidth / (float) previewWidth;
        float heightRatio = (float) viewHeight / (float) previewHeight;

        // To fill the view with the camera preview, while also preserving the correct aspect ratio,
        // it is usually necessary to slightly oversize the child and to crop off portions along one
        // of the dimensions.  We scale up based on the dimension requiring the most correction, and
        // compute a crop offset for the other dimension.
        if (widthRatio > heightRatio) {
            childWidth = viewWidth;
            childHeight = (int) ((float) previewHeight * widthRatio);
            childYOffset = (childHeight - viewHeight) / 2;
        } else {
            childWidth = (int) ((float) previewWidth * heightRatio);
            childHeight = viewHeight;
            childXOffset = (childWidth - viewWidth) / 2;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
            // One dimension will be cropped.  We shift child over or up by this offset and adjust
            // the size to maintain the proper aspect ratio.
            getChildAt(i).layout(
                    -1 * childXOffset, -1 * childYOffset,
                    childWidth - childXOffset, childHeight - childYOffset);
        }

        try {
            startIfReady();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
        }
    }


    private boolean isPortraitMode() {
        int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            return false;
        }
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            return true;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "isPortraitMode returning false by default");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**GraphicOverlay.java**

```
package com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker.ui.camera;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class GraphicOverlay extends View {
    private final Object mLock = new Object();
    private int mPreviewWidth;
    private float mWidthScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    private int mPreviewHeight;
    private float mHeightScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    private int mFacing = CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
    private Set<Graphic> mGraphics = new HashSet<>();

    public static abstract class Graphic {
        private GraphicOverlay mOverlay;

        public Graphic(GraphicOverlay overlay) {
            mOverlay = overlay;
        }


        public abstract void draw(Canvas canvas);


        public float scaleX(float horizontal) {
            return horizontal * mOverlay.mWidthScaleFactor;
        }

        public float scaleY(float vertical) {
            return vertical * mOverlay.mHeightScaleFactor;
        }


        public float translateX(float x) {
            if (mOverlay.mFacing == CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                return mOverlay.getWidth() - scaleX(x);
            } else {
                return scaleX(x);
            }
        }


        public float translateY(float y) {
            return scaleY(y);
        }

        public void postInvalidate() {
            mOverlay.postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    public GraphicOverlay(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    public void clear() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mGraphics.clear();
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void add(Graphic graphic) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mGraphics.add(graphic);
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public void remove(Graphic graphic) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mGraphics.remove(graphic);
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }


    public void setCameraInfo(int previewWidth, int previewHeight, int facing) {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mPreviewWidth = previewWidth;
            mPreviewHeight = previewHeight;
            mFacing = facing;
        }
        postInvalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Draws the overlay with its associated graphic objects.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        synchronized (mLock) {
            if ((mPreviewWidth != 0) && (mPreviewHeight != 0)) {
                mWidthScaleFactor = (float) canvas.getWidth() / (float)mPreviewWidth;
                mHeightScaleFactor = (float) canvas.getHeight() / (float) mPreviewHeight;
            }

            for (Graphic graphic : mGraphics) {
                graphic.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the captured image to *FaceDetector* API and crop it thereafter.

```
fun getFace(context: Context, data: ByteArray): Bitmap? {
    try {
        val imageStrem = ByteArrayInputStream(data)
        var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStrem)
        if (bitmap.width > bitmap.height) {
            val matrix = Matrix()
            matrix.postRotate(270f)
            if (bitmap.width > 1500) matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f)
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, matrix, true)
        }
        val faceDetector = FaceDetector.Builder(context).setProminentFaceOnly(true).setTrackingEnabled(false).build()
        val frame = Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build()
        val faces = faceDetector.detect(frame)
        var results: Bitmap? = null
        for (i in 0 until faces.size()) {
            val thisFace = faces.valueAt(i)
            val x = thisFace.position.x
            val y = thisFace.position.y
            val x2 = x / 4 + thisFace.width
            val y2 = y / 4 + thisFace.height
            results = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, x.toInt(), y.toInt(), x2.toInt(), y2.toInt())
        }
        return results
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("GET_FACE", e.message)
    }
    return null
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/bako-ak/face-detection/blob/master/app/src/main/java/kz/bako/facedetection/face/FaceUtil.kt)